# Loop over character variables in R

Tags: r, for-loop

*I've read the related questions here, but I'm struggling to adapt the answers to my code.

I am trying to run the following command:

```
clist = c("QB", "WR", "TE", "RB")
for (i in unique(data$clist)) {
   data_i = subset(data, data$position == i)
}
```

to create subsets of my data for the different football positions (i.e. data_QB, data_WR, data_TE, data_RB).

However, this is not working. I understand that this is because R doesn't recognize that I'm trying to use "i" as a string variable, but don't know how to fix my code. Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split`

```
lst1 <- split(data, data$position)
names(lst1) <- paste0("data_", names(lst1))
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or if we want to use a `for` loop, use `assign`

```
for(val in clist) {
   assign(paste0('data_', val), subset(data, position == val))
 }
```